# Mysql-python, Variable for request?

Tags: python, mysql, loops, variables, mysql-python

**Table groups:**

| id_group | name | create_time | update_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Salsa | 2023-03-18 | NULL |
| 2 | HipHop | 2023-03-19 | NULL |
| 3 | Waltz | 2023-03-22 | NULL |
| 4 | Foxtrot | 2023-04-01 | NULL |
| 5 | Quickstep | 2023-04-01 | NULL |
| 6 | Foxtrot Pro | 2023-04-04 | NULL |

**Table calendar:**

| id_c | fulldate | fulltime | dayOfWeek | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1232 | record | record | record | NULL | 2 | NULL | 4 | NULL | NULL |
| 2233 | record | record | record | NULL | 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3342 | record | record | record | NULL | NULL | 3 | NULL | NULL | 6 |
| 4422 | record | record | record | NULL | NULL | 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5442 | record | record | record | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6 |
| 6324 | record | record | record | NULL | 2 | NULL | 4 | NULL | NULL |

```
import mysql.connector

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='ck4',
                                         user='user',
                                         password='user')

    Query = "SELECT `id_group` FROM groups"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(Query)

    records = cursor.fetchall()
    
    for rows in records:
        row = (rows[0])
        
        print(row)
        >>>>
        1
        2
        3
        4
        5
        6
        >>>>

    
        sql_select_Query = """SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `%s` = '%s'""" % (row, row)

        

except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        connection.close()
        cursor.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Request works fine.

```
sql_select_Query = """SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `%s` = '%s'""" % (row, row)
```

The request is processed in a loop for each id:

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `1` = '1';
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `2` = '2';
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `3` = '3';
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `4` = '4';
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `5` = '5';
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `6` = '6';
```

How can I make another request like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `1` = '1' OR `2` = '2' OR `3` = '3' OR `4` = '4' OR `5` = '5' OR `6` = '6';
```

Comment: If all your columns are *either a positive number or null* then you only need to check ```WHERE `1` OR `2` OR `3` OR `4` OR `5` OR `6` ```. Weird naming convention for your columns though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join()` to concatenate all the column names with `OR` delimiters.

```
Query = "SELECT `id_group` FROM groups"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(Query)

groups = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
condition = ' OR '.join(f"`{group}` = '{group}'" for group in groups
sql_select_Query = f"SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE {condition}"
```

Note that a table design with dynamic column names like this is generally a poor idea, it means that you'll have to write dynamic SQL most of the time. Dynamic information should be in column values, not column names.

Comment: - The request completed successfully. Thank you )
- By the structure of dynamic information, I completely agree with you. But It is what it is.